# MySQL Sum Query Based on Same Row Value

Tags: mysql, sum

I want to make total sum based on same row value, but since other rows not same value, I don't know how to do it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3oz4.png)

Suppose the table like as follow:

```
City           ID    Date          Lic.Plate    No.Order        Dest.    Fee1      Fee2         Fee3        Fee4       Fee5      Fee6      Total
    SUKABUMI    6   2021-09-16      B-9944-FXR  ORD-00005       BANDUNG  1000000   120000.00    0.00        0.00        0.00    0.00    120000.00
    CIANJUR     6   2021-09-16      B-9944-FXR  ORD-00005       BANDUNG  1000000   1500000.00   100000.00   50000.00    0.00    0.00    1650000.00
    BOGOR       7   2021-09-16      B-9944-FXR  ORD-00006       BANDUNG  700000         0.00    100000.00   0.00        0.00    0.00    100000.00
    BOGOR       7   2021-09-16      B-9944-FXR  ORD-00006       BANDUNG  700000         0.00    100000.00   50000.00    0.00    0.00    150000.00
```

Now, What I really want is to show the total it should value Fee1+Fee2+Fee3+Fee4+Fee5+Fee6 and result should 1.770.000 because Row#1 and Row#2 have the same value for [No.Order]
While Row#3 and Row#4 the total should be 250.000 because [No.Order] have same value.

This is my query :

```
SELECT City
      ,ID
      ,Date
      ,Lic.Plate
      ,No.Order
      ,Dest
      ,Fee1
      ,Fee2
      ,Fee3
      ,Fee4
      ,Fee5
      ,Fee6
      ,SUM(Fee1+Fee2+Fee3+Fee+Fee5+Fee6) AS total 
FROM tborder 
  INNER JOIN tbmobil on tbmobil.idmobil=tborder.idmobil    
  INNER JOIN tbsj ON tbsj.noorder=tborder.noorder 
  INNER JOIN tbinvdet on tbsj.idsj=tbinvdet.idsj 
  LEFT  JOIN tbso ON tbso.idsj=tbsj.idsj   
GROUP BY No.Order, City
```

Can someone help me with this query ?
Thank you very much

Comment: how result become  1.770.000 and 250.000?

Comment: the 1st and 2nd row should show 1.770.000 because 1.650 + 120 (due to same No.Order), and 3rd, 4th should 250.000 due same No.Order column value. Why I need this ? because in report devexpress the same value in row will be merge for duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a join to compute this
Do a group by order no. and sum(fees1+fees2+... ), this will give you 1770,000 in first case
Now join this with your main table on order no.

```
Select a.*, b.result from
tborder a
left join
(Select order, sum(fees1+fees2+...) result from tborder
Group by order) b
On a.order=b.order
```

Comment: Any insight how to implement in my query ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Updated with query